# Duplicate schema resoponse attribute in swagger ui

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

My model looks like this:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Schema(description = "Contains list of strings")
public class MyResponse {

    @Schema(requiredMode = RequiredMode.REQUIRED, description = "List of my sample strings")
    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    @NotNull
    private List<String> myMessages;
}
```

Now, when I see my swagger ui, it looks like this:

[image]

Why is it printing myMessages twice? Shouldn't it just print once?
I am using springdoc openapi ui 1.7.0

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the description only for Array by using @ArraySchema annotation. Here is a simple example:

```
@ArraySchema(arraySchema = @Schema(description = "This is a list"))
List<String> items = new HashSet<>();
```

You can find the same question in this springdoc issue.
https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/330